# Enabling wide tile for a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app with WMS

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app that I need to switch to WMS. When using WMS, the tile definitions from `WMAppManifest.xml` are no longer used, all the tiles are defined in `Package.appxmanifest`.

The problem is, in `Package.appxmanifest` there is no UI for setting the tiles. When I open the file as XML, I can see no definition for a wide tile.

So how do I add the wide tile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember, I added the wide tile directly in the XML.  And I've that kind of lines (check the Wide310x150Logo property) :

```
 <Application Id="xxxxx" Executable="AGHost.exe" EntryPoint="View/MainPage.xaml">
  <m3:VisualElements DisplayName="SeriesManiac" Square150x150Logo="Assets\150x150.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Logo.png" Description="SeriesManiac" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="transparent" ToastCapable="true">
    <m3:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\WideLogo.png" Square71x71Logo="Assets\71x71.png">
    </m3:DefaultTile>
    <m3:SplashScreen Image="Assets\Splashscreen.png" />
  </m3:VisualElements>
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="AgHost.BackgroundTask">
      <BackgroundTasks>
        <Task Type="systemEvent" />
      </BackgroundTasks>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
</Application>
```